# a kind of kmean clustering

Tags: python, module, scalar

I tried to run this code in python2.7 with a matrix 20*20 and i want to get two cluster just like the kmean algorithm.

**js**

```js
import numpy as np

filename = np.genfromtxt('Matrix.txt')
M = np.sort (np.random.choice (2,20)) 

##m = np.copy(M) => I get an error there : 'module' object is not callable
M= m  #this option work better but i am not sure that it is appropriate

#initialization of the clusters
C = {}

for t in xrange(tmax=100):
 #determination of clusters
 J = np.mean(filename[:,M], axis = 1)
 for k in range (2):
  C[k] = np.where (J==k, 0,0) # np.where (J==k)=> another error for 'np.where': it take exactly three arguments but one given.I saw that it could take only one argument

 #update  
 for k in range (2):
  J = np.mean(filename[np.ix_(C[k],C[k])], axis = 1)
  j= np.argmin(J)
  m[k] = C[k][j] #[j]  => another error for '[j]': invalid index to scalar variable

    #results
print M, C
```

**my result**

> {0 : 0, 1:0}

**the expected result**

> {0:8, 1:12}

in example meaning that there is 8 elements in cluster '0' and 12 in cluster '1'.
This is probably because of 'np.where ' function but i am not sure.

I run the program without all the errors that i previously mentioned for get this result but it doesn't work as well it should

Thanks for your help

Comment: The code has multiple issues, `M` is initialized to an array after that is changed to an unknown `m`, tmax is undefined. You want `m=M.copy()` but instead is done `M=m`. And  why mean? In k_means you need to calculate the distance between two vectors.

Comment: edited . @valentin 'tmax' refer to the number of iteration, and a want to make a copy of 'M' in order to add more conditions and then save the first version. this is not exactly the kmean: my matrix is already an euclidean distance matrix

Comment: from docs:    `where(condition, [x, y]) 

Return elements, either from x or y, depending on condition ` so your where will always return 0

Comment: exactly, but without conditions, i can't run the code so i just tried it for have a better view of my mistakes. Any idea about how i can get the expected result?

Comment: You calculate J as mean values and I suppose these mean values will neither be 0 or 1 so your `where` will return empty data

Comment: yeah, of course! But i couldn't know exactly the type or the size of the values, it could be an int or float. I just know that I should get two kind of values, meaning two 'mean' for the two clusters and then  each value will be associate to the closest mean

Answer (score 0):

Another variant (it uses scikit library):

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import cluster

n_clusters = 2

k_means = cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters)
k_means.fit(filename)
values = k_means.cluster_centers_
labels = k_means.labels_

print values
print labels
```

Comment: It couldn't work.  the program is suppose to choose between my 20*20 values, only '2' values; just like the k_mean algorithm. and this '2' values are so closest to the others that they could be consider as mean.

Comment: in exemple : the mean of this cluster [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] is 4,5 . so the program should run and select all the closest values around this mean

Comment: unfortunately i can't download a new package on the server that i'am using now. I will checked it on my own computer in few hours(3). I will come back for give you an answer. Thanks for you help

Comment: Hi,I am back. I got a ValueError....                                                                                                                                                           ValueError: n_samples=1 should be >= n_clusters=2.                                Anyway I read informations about  scikit library and KMeans is already implemented. For my problem I need to create another alternative and I don't really succeed.thanks for helping

Comment: there are simple implementations of k-meas in py. try search for kmeas.py, but they need to be adapted to your needs

Comment: try `k_means.fit(x.T)` instead of `k_means.fit(x)`